# Graphics (HDMI) driver not defined

Tags: pulseaudio

I have a dell vostro 3500 which used to run Ubuntu just fine (14.04). I've switched to Kubuntu (14.04) to give it a go and I have a problem with the HDMI. There is no option to output sound via HDMI. it seems like it's not defined.

this is what lspci returns:
"VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Core Processor Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 18)"

I've also tried intel graphics installer.

Any ideas what's wrong? 
Feel free to ask any additional information.

Comment: @guntbert why I shouldn't?